# Bug in Visual Studio, don't know what to do

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

After closing and reopening the project in Visual Studio, the asp .net core project stopped seeing all dependent classes and interfaces, in particular IActionResult, class NameController : *Controller* and absolutely everything. Please tell me how to solve the problem and has anyone encountered this?

[image]
[image]

all my actions are powerless

Comment: We can find there are two namespaces can't be using correctly in your first screenshot. My suggestion is you  can try delete these folders (`bin`,`obj`,`.vs`) and check if it is resloved.

Comment: If it still not works, could you use another PC/ or re-install VS2022 for test, it seems there are some environment settings were changed. Reboot the computer is also welcome.

Comment: I also started with a simple one, deleted the entire temporary directory, cleaned up the project, and restarted the computer. But nothing helped. I decided to open another project on . NET 5, the same. I assume that the error is in the IDE or . NET. I have deleted the current version of VS and will reinstall it.

Comment: Maybe some specific software or anti-virus did it ? You need to check this if reinstall vs2022 still not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that helped in solving this problem was reinstalling VS (to a more recent version) and all related .NET components.

After that, in the application properties, you must specify the Assembly name and the default namespace.